# Multiclass ROC curve about one vs one

Tags: classification, data-mining, roc, auc, multi-class

I am learning ROC about multiclass problem.
I read this article https://towardsdatascience.com/multiclass-classification-evaluation-with-roc-curves-and-roc-auc-294fd4617e3a .

I am confused about ovo problem. Is “Class1 vs Class2” is different than “Class2 vs Class1”? I read other paper saying that n classes will only prodeuce n(n-1)/2 ROC curves.

But if “Class1 vs Class2” is different than “Class2 vs Class1”. It will prodeuce n(n-1) ROC curves. I don't know which is correct